# How to preserve newlines and whitespaces in Jmeter parameters

Tags: parameters, jmeter, newline, whitespace

[image]Hi i need to add a piece of code to my Jmeter parameters for my request as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
//use cin to get console input 
string test;
getline(cin,test);

vector<char> newstr;
for (int i = 0; i< test.size();i++)
{
char c = test[i];
if ((c>='a'&& c <='z') || (c>='A'&& c <='Z'))
{
    //cout<<"c: "<<c<<endl;
    newstr.push_back(tolower(c));
}
}

if (newstr.size()==0)
{
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
for (int i = 0; i< newstr.size()/2;i++)
{
char a = newstr[i];
char b = newstr[newstr.size()-1-i];
if (a != b)
{
    //cout<<newstr[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

}
cout<<"YES"<<endl; 

//use cout to print console output 

return 0; 
}
```

However, when i add it as a parameter, it takes the entire code in a single line and never executes it. i.e. it takes it as follows:

```
#include <string> #include <vector> #include <iostream>  using namespace std;   int main()  {  //use cin to get console input  string test; getline(cin,test);  vector<char> newstr; for (int i = 0; i< test.size();i++) { char c = test[i]; if ((c>='a'&& c <='z') || (c>='A'&& c <='Z')) {    //cout<<"c: "<<c<<endl;     newstr.push_back(tolower(c)); } }  if (newstr.size()==0) {  cout<<"YES"<<endl;      return 0;   } for (int i = 0; i< newstr.size()/2;i++) { char a = newstr[i]; char b = newstr[newstr.size()-1-i]; if (a != b) {   //cout<<newstr[i]<<endl;    cout<<"NO"<<endl;   return 0; }  } cout<<"YES"<<endl;   //use cout to print console output   return 0;  }
```

and never executes the code.

Also, the code works fine in postman as it accepts whitespaces and newline characters..

**I tried it using the escape sequence but it doesn't work for me**. Is there any way out?

The parameters are as follows:

```
requestid:2
store:${hdn_store}
txtsol: #include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
//use cin to get console input 
string test;
getline(cin,test);

vector<char> newstr;
for (int i = 0; i< test.size();i++)
{
char c = test[i];
if ((c>='a'&& c <='z') || (c>='A'&& c <='Z'))
{
    //cout<<"c: "<<c<<endl;
    newstr.push_back(tolower(c));
}
}

if (newstr.size()==0)
{
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
for (int i = 0; i< newstr.size()/2;i++)
{
char a = newstr[i];
char b = newstr[newstr.size()-1-i];
if (a != b)
{
    //cout<<newstr[i]<<endl;
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

}
cout<<"YES"<<endl; 

//use cout to print console output 

return 0; 
}

langcode:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches, for example:

1. Store your code into the file and use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function to read it from the file system
2. Convert the code into [Base64 format](https://www.base64encode.org/), it will result in a single line like:

   ```
   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
   ```

and use [__base64Decode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Decodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) to convert it back in the HTTP Request sampler parameters section

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept